# Why is my pointer giving back value at address directly?

Tags: c, pointers

Here is my code:

```
typedef struct {
    int** matrix;
    int rows;
    int cols;
}intMat;
intMat create_intMat(int rows,int cols,int matrix[rows][cols]){
        intMat A;
        A.rows = rows;
        A.cols = cols;
        int** mat;
        mat = malloc(A.rows*sizeof(int*)); // Pointer for matrix rows
        for(int i=0;i<A.rows;i++) mat[i] = malloc(A.cols*sizeof(int)); // Pointer of each matrix row to a matrix column
        for (int i=0;i<A.rows;i++){
            for (int j=0;j<A.cols;j++){
                mat[i][j]=matrix[i][j];
            }
        }
        A.matrix = mat;
        return A;
}
int main() {

        int mat[2][2] = {{1,2},{3,4}};
        intMat A;
        A = create_intMat(2,2,mat);

        printf("%d\n",A.matrix[1][1]);

        return 0;
}
```

I'm a beginner to pointers and got the pointer part of the code from another forum. I don't get it, though. int** mat is a pointer to a pointer to an int, so if I call it as is then it should give me back gibberish address, not the int being pointed to. However, the printf statement returns 4, which is the value of the int being pointed to! How come this is happening?

Comment: Actually, you are dereferencing it twice through the use of the `[]` operator. Remember that `a[b]` is *defined* to be equivalent to `*(a+b)`, so when you write `mat[1][1]` you are doing `*(*(mat+1)+1)`, which, as you see, is dereferencing `mat` twice, getting from `int **` to `int`.

Comment: @MatteoItalia -- you should consider posting that as an answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use:

```
int i;
int* p = &i;
```

or

```
int* p = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

`p` points to a single integer.

When you use:

```
int array[10];
int *p = array;
```

or

```
int *p = malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
```

`p` points to an array of 10 integers.

Similarly, a variable declared with:

```
int** mat;
```

can point to one `int*` or an array of `int*`s.

In your case, `mat` points to an array of 2 `int*`, each of which points to an array of 2 `int`s.

That makes use of `mat[1][1]` perfectly valid code.

Comment: in your code `int *p = array;` should it not instead be `int *p = &array;`? And thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

`A.matrix` is a pointer to a 2 pointers, which each point to 2 ints.
`A.matrix[1]` gets the second of those pointers - a pointer to 2 ints.
`A.matrix[1][1]` gets the second of those ints.